Showing that $|f|$ integrable $\implies$ $f$ integrable, from Friedman's definition of integrability
I'm trying to solve the following problem from Friedman's Foundations of Modern Analysis, paraphrased:

2.6.3. Let $f$ be a measurable function. Prove that $f$ is integrable if and only if $f^+$ and $f^-$ are integrable, or if and only if $|f|$ is integrable.

The only part I am having trouble with is the implication
$$\text{$|f|$ integrable} \implies \text{$f$ integrable.}$$
This question addresses the same issue, but the answer seems to be using a different definition of integrability than Friedman; one where the integrability of $|f|$ immediately implies integrability of $f^+$ and $f^-$. Friedman uses the following definition:

Definition 2.6.1 An extended real-valued, measurable function $f$, on a measure space $(X, \mathcal A, \mu)$ is said to be integrable if there exists a sequence $\{f_n\}$ of integrable simple functions having the following properties:
(a) $\{f_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence in the mean.
(b) $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = f(x)$ a.e.

Also, it has been proven that (b) can be replaced by the following property:

(b') $\{f_n\}$ converges in measure to $f$.

I've tried several approaches, mostly to prove
$$\text{$|f|$ integrable} \implies \text{$f^+$ (and $f^-$) integrable,}$$
which would be sufficient, since I have already proven that integrability of $f^+$ and $f^-$ implies integrability of $f$.
If $|f|$ is integrable then there is a sequence $\{g_n\}$ of integrable simple functions which satisfies (a) and (b) (or (a) and (b')) with respect to $|f|$. I need to somehow construct a sequence $\{h_n\}$ of integrable simple functions from this, which satisfies (a) and (b) (or (a) and (b')) with respect to $f^+$. The difficulty is to somehow get the sign information, because I need to get it directly from $f$, which is not a simple function.
My most promising approach was to write each $g_n$ as
$$g_n = \sum_{i=1}^{k_n} \alpha_{n,i} \chi_{E_{n,i}},$$
with each $\chi_{E_{n,i}}$ denoting the characteristic function of a measurable subset $E_{n,i}$, and each $\alpha_{n,i}$ being a real constant, and then define
$$
h_n = \sum_{i=1}^{k_n} \beta_{n,i} \chi_{E_{n,i}}, \quad \beta_{n,i} =
\begin{cases}
  |\alpha_{n,i}| & \text{if $f \ge 0$ a.e. on $E_i$,} \\
  0 & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}
$$
This sequence satisfies (a), but I was not able to show that it satifies (b) or (b') with respect to $f^+$.
Is there a way to go forward with this approach, or do I need to try something else entirely? Any advice?

Let $E:=[f\ge0]$. If $g_n\to|f|$ a.e. then $g_n\mathbf1_E\to|f|\mathbf1_E=f^+$ a.e.

Thanks! Can't believe I didn't see that; I guess I was too caught up in more complicated ideas.
